# Apache ProxyPass - receiving 404 page not found

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy

I am using apache first time to manage sites. The issue is when I add `ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:888/` It works but when I change it to `ProxyPass /swarmpit http://127.0.0.1:888/`, it doesn't work and I get 404 page not found. Below is the explanation in screenshots.

My `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` looks like
[image]

When I access swarmpit, it says 404 not found.
[image]

But when I change `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` to
[image]

It works fine

[image]

Is there anything I am missing to access /swampit

Comment: Try `ProxyPass /swarmpit/ http://127.0.0.1:888/` .. the ending slash might be missing.

Comment: In your curl command you are using `swampit` and in your conf file, you are using `swarmpit`. misspell.

Comment: ahh that's the issue :-) .. BTW, adding /at the end worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misspelled the URL in your curl command. In your curl command you are using `swampit` and in your conf file, you are using `swarmpit`.